# Dependencies in Android Library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to use `recyclerView` in my library. 
 I just compile it in gradle (Library module):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1' 
}
```

In other projects, it's look like that:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'ru.alexbykov:nopaginate' //my library
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1' 
  }
```

`RecyclerView` is connected twice (In my current project and in my library which is located in `jcenter` )

Is it possible to connect a `recyclerView` only in the project module? (not in library)?

Comment: Does your library uses recyclerView as well?

Comment: @Andrew Lam Yep

Comment: Are you sure there's a problem? Run this to check, what you think is what is fact:  `gradle -q dependencies` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> RecyclerView is connected twice (In my current project and in my library which is located in jcenter )

This is not a problem. The project could remove its dependency on `recyclerview-v7` if desired.

> Is it possible to connect a recyclerView only in the project module? (not in library)?

Only by not using `RecyclerView` in the library.

Comment: I think if library is using `recyclerview` and project too then it should also work right ?

Comment: @Nancy: If you are referring to "RecyclerView is connected twice", then yes, this is not a problem.